# Python - Getting TypeError when trying to save numpy array using Image.fromarray of PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, typeerror

I have been trying to use PIL for loading and storing images with the help of numpy arrays.

I am trying to load an image of dimensions 192x192 , pad it to make it 256x256 and then store it back.

Here is the script which I am trying to run :

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
import numpy as np

#function to pad to 256x256
def pad_2d(data, r, c):
    res = np.zeros((r,c))
    m, n = data.shape
    
    res[(r-m)//2:(r-m)//2+m , (c-n)//2:(c-n)//2+n] = data
    return res

#function to remove padding
def crop_2d(data, r, c):
    m, n = data.shape
    
    return data[(m-r)//2:(m-r)//2+r , (n-c)//2:(n-c)//2+c]

file = "img1.png"

#image is successfully loaded in the form of numpy array and normalized 

data = asarray(Image.open(file)) # the data loaded, is of the shape (192,192,4)
data = (255.0 / data.max() * (data - data.min())).astype(np.uint8)

# dummy numpy array to store the 256x256 variant of 192x192 image by padding zeros
t = np.zeros((256,256,4))
for i in range(4):
    t[:,:,i] = pad_2d(data[:,:,i],256,256)
    
print(data.shape, t.shape) # prints : (192, 192, 4) (256, 256, 4)

img = Image.fromarray(t) # error occurs in this line
img.save('img2.png')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 4), <f8
```

I have cross-checked both `pad_2d` and `crop_2d` functions. They both work as expected. If I try to execute `img = Image.fromarray(data)` instead, then it runs fine by saving the same image as expected.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inadvertently making a float array. Change to this:

```
t = np.zeros((256,256,4), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had thought it had something to do with the dimensions.